# Relating/ Duplicating Own Questions

Tags: support, flagging

Is it allowed to duplicate your own question but where it won't get marked [duplicate]?
ex. q: Can I give surgery to my fish
Q: Is it ok to give surgery to a fish because I want to give surgery to my fish.
They are two separate examples of 2 questions being duplicated vise versa
Are you allowed to do something like this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. Do you mean "are you allowed to repeat an answer word for word and not have the question be marked duplicate"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the discussion on Meta StackExchange about how to handle duplicate questions: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Note their recommendation for closing duplicate questions:

> **If I can, should I (vote to) close the question?**
>
> It depends. If a question is an exact duplicate, then go ahead and
>   (vote to) close it. However, note that questions may be similar
>   without being exact duplicates:
>
> [From the blog:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/)
>
> There could be hundreds of different, related, perfectly valid
>   questions on the same topic. There is no One True Question.
>
> and...
>
> It's rarely this straightforward, however -- usually there are two
>   similar but not-quite-the-same questions, both of which have value for
>   different reasons.

Basically, duplicate questions are bad because they divide answers and create noise across the site. The purpose of Stack Exchange is for people to search and find one question with all the answers, and not have to search between multiple pages/site.

It is possible to have a question that is extremely similar to another and not be a duplicate, but the question has to clarify how it's different from the other question, and why the answers to that question aren't going to answer the question, in order to be clear that it's not a duplicate.

It's important to note that even though the question might be worded differently, it can still be considered a duplicate if it seeks the same answers as another question, and not liking the current answers to an existing question are not reasons for re-asking it, in that case a bounty should be placed on the question to attract more attention.